# failing to give expand to container in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]I am making simple todo app where there is a widget TodoWidget contains 3 part

first checkbox
than todo detail and title as column
than a delete button

here I don't want to use list tile as learning designing

I have used Gesturedetector to tap on title for edit todo,
but this portion is based on text size..if title is small I have to click exactly on title

I want to give as much space as I can for title whether it is small

and if title is long it should show like '...' at the end

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: todo.color,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            todo.isdone==false?Checkbox(
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                checkColor: Colors.red,
                value: todo.isdone,
                onChanged: (value) {
                 final result= Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context,listen: false).toogletodo(todo);
                }):IconButton(onPressed: (){
                    final result= Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context,listen: false).toogletodo(todo);
            }, icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: todo.isdone?null:(){
                editrecord(context);
              },
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  //here i want to give maximum area to this container
                  
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(todo.title,style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(height: 6,),
                         if (todo.description.isNotEmpty)
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            todo.description,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {

                Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context,listen: false).deletetodo(todo);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red,)),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to expand container of title

Comment: add `width: double.infinity,` to the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give expand as parent of GestureDetector like this:

```
Expanded(
 child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: todo.isdone?null:(){
                editrecord(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  ...
              ),
         ),   
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For showing `...` at the end of long text you should use

```
Text(
  'text here',
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

And wrap your text widget in `Container` and give some width so you have to tap on container not on text